# Android: How to make a layout that fits multiple screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

[image]

as You can see it has numbers in each one of the circles. I have created it using RelativeLayout and then playing with the margins of each TextView, and it looks good on my Nexus 4.

But obviously when i use a different device with different resolution, everything looks messed up since the margins are set for a specific screen size/density.

Looking around the web i saw that i can't use percentage so how can i make this layout fit all screen sizes?

Here is how i did it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/circleContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="zoomCircle" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/packages_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numOfEnv"
        style="@style/whiteCircleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
        android:text="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numSmall"
        style="@style/whiteCircleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomMargin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
        android:text="20" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numMedium"
        style="@style/whiteCircleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomMargin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:text="30" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numBig"
        style="@style/whiteCircleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/circleImg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
        android:text="740" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to create each object and add into layout programatically, and using ratio for each object. For example: ratio of your screen is 9/16.

height = size.y;
width = ratio * height;

Every object will set layout param or margin param, they should follow this width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using dimensions. Make a different `values` folder for each screen size you'd like to support, ie `values-sw320dp`, `values-sw600dp`, etc. Each with its own dimens.xml file. Then, put different values for leftMargin, topMargin, etc in each dimens file. Look at the section "Using new size qualifiers" [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info.

Comment: Mike, thanks i know about this solution but still it is not perfect, first of all it's a lot of work (I want to support from version 2.3), but i wouldn't mind it if it actually worked, but i ran it on nexus4 and Galaxy s4 and on the galaxy s4 the margins were a bit off. Looks like the only solution here is doing it programatically.